# How can I list packages selected manually via yum?

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, rpm

I'm working on a CentOS system where I install packages, occasionally, with `yum install whatever`. And, of course, some packages are dragged in as dependencies.

Is it possible to get  a listing of all those packages which were installed due to specific user request rather than dependency satisfaction?

And if so, can this be limited by date range or by whether it was during the initial distribution installation or later?

Comment: Have a look at `yum history`.

Comment: @JRFerguson: Interesting, but how can I get it to list package names? It only shows me dates, usernames, action names and number of packages influenced.

Comment: `yum history info <spec>`

Answer (score 1):

As @JRFerguson suggests, you can use `yum history`. Use it once to get the highest yum action number; then again to get details about those transactions. So, something like this:

```
last_action_index=$(yum history | head -4 | tail -1 | sed -r 's/^ *([0-9]+) .*/\1/;')
yum history info 2..${last_action_index} | grep -vi Dep-Install | grep Install | cut -c15-50 | sed -r 's/-([0-9]+:)?(el)?[0-9]+\.(el)?[0-9].*$//; s/^ *//;'
```